# Nginx wildcard root from sub domain with fallback

Tags: nginx

I'm using something like the following as a "default" `vhost` on `Nginx`. I want every sub domain to have an own directory basically.

Can anyone help with a fallback (I'm new to this). If a directory/sub domain doesn't exists I want some kind of custom `404.html` page.

Thanks!

```
server {

    server_name ~^(.+).mysite.com$;

    set $root_path $1;

    root    /var/www/$root_path/public;
    index   index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #Include Nginx’s fastcgi configuration
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        #Look for the FastCGI Process Manager at this location
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server {
...
    error_page 404 /your_custom_404.html;
    location = /your_custom_404.html {
        root /path/to/your_custom_404.html;
        internal;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
    }
...
}
```